# fetch most liked documents in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

likes[asdasd,sadsad]
T
here is a list of UIDs for each post, I determine the most likes according to the length of this list. I want this list to come in order from the longest to the shortest, what should I do?
If I do orderBy descending true will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `likes` is an array, and you want to order the documents according to the length of the array, then you have to add an extra field of type number, for example, `likesLength`, which will hold the length of the array. Then you can then perform a query and order the results ascending according to this field.

One thing to note would be that you'll have to update the array each time a new like is added or removed. This can be done from the client-side code, but more elegant it will be to use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort by the length of the array

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types

I would create a new filed called `likesCount`  and use Cloud Function to update the numbers

here is an example code:

```js
export const updateLikesCount = functions.firestore.document('posts/{postId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

    const beforeData = change.before.data();
    const afterData = change.after.data();

    // Check if the likes array has been updated
    if (beforeData.likes.length !== afterData.likes.length) {

      // Update the likes count
      await postRef.update({ likesCount: afterData.likes.length });

      console.log(`Updated likes count for post ${context.params.postId}: ${afterData.likes.length}`);

    }
  });
```